# Hardware reference manual for ethernet mac in bcm2711

Tags: ethernet, kernel

I recently bought a RPi4 model B for learning the Linux device drivers particularly the Ethernet MAC. I was looking for a documentation, something similar to [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruh73q/spruh73q.pdf) one which is for AM335x from TI, but couldn't find it. I am surprised that a giant like Broadcom would not release the documentation for their bcm2711.  
 If I have mistaken could someone please point me towards a documentation at least regarding the GENet controller on the bcm2711.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - we're surprised also - even after all these years!

The sad truth is you'll find no documentation from Broadcom similar in scope to the TI document you've referenced. The closest perhaps is the [BCM2711 Peripherals document](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/bcm2711/bcm2711-peripherals.pdf). By way of comparison, TI's AM335X TRM document weighs in at over 5,000 pages *vs.* 160 pages for the "detailed document" released by Broadcom/Raspberry Pi organization.

It may not be *fair* to compare RPi's BCM2711 document to TI's AM335X *by volume*, but I feel it's entirely accurate to state that Broadcom and RPi.org are quite [*penurious*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/penurious) with their documentation. Worse, they seem to be headed in the wrong direction; i.e. *reducing* the available documentation; [e.g. 1](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/issues/1915), [2](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/issues/2588), [3](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/issues/2233).

There are also the odd, but very useful, bits scattered about the Internet from "the early days" [for example](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/issues/971), so it pays to search broadly.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer, However, I still had a question in mind. I was wondering, how do other OS vendors like FreeBSD, RISC OS, Windows 10 IoT core, manage to port their existing OS to the new hardware ?

Comment: @HungryFoolish: They might gain access to the firmware sources through a NDA (non-disclosure agreement) - or a reasonably detailed specification, or ...